# using Javascript how can I access elements form a json array?

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

Using nomonics crypto api and Javascript with a googlesheets spreadsheet, the returned object is:

```
[
  {
    "circulating_supply": "17591362",
    "high": "24436.29525000",
    "high_timestamp": "2018-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    "market_cap": "70647474650.63",
    "max_supply": "21000000",
    "price": "4016.03211000",
    "currency": "BTC",
    "1d": {
      "market_cap_change": "2334344443.63",
      "market_cap_change_pct": "0.0342",
      "price_change": "132.26230000",
      "price_change_pct": "0.0341",
      "volume": "531837882.13",
      "volume_change": "34633070.11",
      "volume_change_pct": "0.0697"
    },
    "7d": {
      "market_cap_change": "2087829209.46",
      "market_cap_change_pct": "0.0305",
      "price_change": "115.88873000",
      "price_change_pct": "0.0297",
      "volume": "2984154293.31",
      "volume_change": "-872155432.42",
      "volume_change_pct": "-0.2262"
    },
        "rank": "1"
  }
]
```

I can access the price with

```
resp[0].price
```

but when I try to access the 1d and 7d parts I have tried:

```
resp[0].1d.market_cap_change
```

and

```
resp[0]1d.market_cap_change
```

googlesheets does not allow me to save the code with the error:

```
Missing name after . operator. (line 29, file "Code")
```

What is the correct way to access the elements in the 1d and 7d block?

Thank you.

Comment: try resp[0]["1d"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[]` notation as your key is not [**valid JS identifier**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation)

```
resp[0]['1d'].market_cap_change
```

```js
let resp = [{"circulating_supply": "17591362","high": "24436.29525000","high_timestamp": "2018-01-05T00:00:00.000Z","market_cap": "70647474650.63","max_supply": "21000000","price": "4016.03211000","currency": "BTC","1d": {"market_cap_change": "2334344443.63","market_cap_change_pct": "0.0342","price_change":"132.26230000","price_change_pct": "0.0341","volume": "531837882.13","volume_change": "34633070.11","volume_change_pct": "0.0697"},"7d": {"market_cap_change": "2087829209.46","market_cap_change_pct": "0.0305","price_change": "115.88873000","price_change_pct": "0.0297","volume": "2984154293.31","volume_change": "-872155432.42","volume_change_pct": "-0.2262"},"rank": "1"}]

console.log(resp[0]['1d'].market_cap_change)
```